# MongoDB connectivity issue

Tags: java, linux, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongodb server which is running on remote Linux machine using java code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {           
        //load a properties file
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/mongodb.properties"));            
        String server = prop.getProperty("server");
        String port = prop.getProperty("port");
        int portnum = Integer.parseInt(port);

        /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(server,portnum);
        System.out.println("Connected to database");

        /**** Get database ****/
        // if database doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");

        /**** Get collection / table from 'details' ****/
        // if collection doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("details");

        /**** Insert ****/
        // create a document to store key and value
        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("name", "test");
        document.put("age", 24);
        table.insert(document);

        /**** Find and display ****/
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("name", "test");

        DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**It is working fine with my local mongo. But facing an issue while trying to connect with linux server.**

Here is the error message,

```
Jan 18, 2016 12:23:02 AM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection
WARNING: Exception executing isMaster command on server:port
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [server port] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:548)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getMaxBsonObjectSize(Mongo.java:620)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:254)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
    at com.filecompare.util.MongoDBConnection.main(MongoDBConnection.java:42)

Jan 18, 2016 12:23:03 AM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection
WARNING: Exception executing isMaster command on sever port
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [server port] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:143)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:148)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.initDirectConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:548)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:527)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:174)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
    at com.filecompare.util.MongoDBConnection.main(MongoDBConnection.java:42)

Jan 18, 2016 12:23:04 AM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to server:port b/c of error
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [server:port] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
    at com.filecompare.util.MongoDBConnection.main(MongoDBConnection.java:42)

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't say something
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:194)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:270)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:59)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:104)
    at com.filecompare.util.MongoDBConnection.main(MongoDBConnection.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [server port] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:181)
    ... 7 more
```

Steps that I generally follow to connect with mongo on linux are,

1. Login to server using Putty(windows) or ssh command(Mac).
2. type in mongo.
3. Connected to mongo, run mongo commands to view/ insert data.

But, in above java code I didn't include any login credentials. Do I have to do that. If so, could someone please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're providing the right values for your `server` and `port` property variables in `mongodb.properties`?

Default port for MongoDB is `27017`.

Also, check your `mongod.conf` on the MongoDB server. This file is found, by default at `/etc/mongod.conf` and look for the following attribute:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

If this is set to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, then you won't be able to access your MongoDB server publicly from outside.

Now to fix this, change value of `bind_ip` to include your public ip address, so if your public address is `46.12.212.34`, `bind_ip` will look like:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1, 46.12.212.34
```

Save and exit the file and restart your MongoDB database. Your Java application should now work.

Comment: The server and port details that I'm using are right. I will have to validate bind_ip in mongod.conf. But, I couldn't find mongod.conf file both in my local mongodb server and on linux machine.

Comment: Is it in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`? How did you install MongoDB?

Comment: I ran mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.1-signed.msi file after downloading it. There is no mongod.conf file in my local windows machine.

Comment: It won't be on your local machine. It'll be on the MongoDB server. Is your database server windows or linux?